# ¿Cómo hacer multiples instacias de variables globales o dinámicas en C#?

Tags: c#, variables, hilos, unity

Me gustaría saber si es posible tener multiples instacias/hilos de variables en C# tal y como se puede hacer en C++. ([ver este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676333/how-to-make-multiple-instances-of-global-variables-in-c)).

Resultalta que tengo un método perteneciente a una clase que usa una serie de variables y funciones pertenecientes a la misma clase. Necesito usar exactamente el mismo código dos veces y lo único que cambiaria es una sola variable. El problema es que el las dos instacias del método se ejecutarían simultaneamente y van a acceder a las mimsmas variables "globales" y por tanto seguro que me va a funcionar mal.

La única solución que se me ocurre es duplicar el código completamente o hacer que esas variables que se comparten sean hilos (threads) como los de C++.

A continuación dejo mi código por si sirve lo quieren ver:

```
public partial class FoxyLadyMove : CommonComponents
{
    bool isItAWayToGetDown;
    bool isItAWayToGetUp;
    bool leftSideChecking; 
    bool rightSideChecking;
    bool leftSideChecked;  
    bool rightSideChecked;

    ///--------------------------------------------------
    /// Comprobar si hay camino de subida
    ///--------------------------------------------------
    private bool IsItAWayToGetUp(Vector2 direction)
    {
        float distance = 4f;
        Vector2 origin = transform.GetPosition();
        return !this.IsRoof(origin, direction, distance);
    }
    ///--------------------------------------------------
    /// Comprobar si hay una caída
    ///--------------------------------------------------
    private bool IsItAWayToGetDown(Vector2 direction)
    {
        float distance = 4f;
        Vector2 origin = transform.GetPosition();
        return !this.IsFloor(origin, direction, distance);
    }
    ///----------------------------------------------------
    /// buscar un camino para subir 
    ///----------------------------------------------------

    //buscar el borde de la plataforma
    private bool SearchWayToGetUp()
    {

        //Si el player no está arriba salimos sin hacer nada
        if (!this.IsUp(player))
            return false;

        //Si se encuentra una subida paramos
        if (isItAWayToGetUp)
        {
            rigidBody.StopX();
            return true;
        }

        //encontramos un obstáculo en medio del camino
        if (isObstacle && leftSideChecking)
        {
            leftSideChecking = false;
            leftSideChecked = true;
        }

         //encontramos un obstáculo en medio del camino
        if (isObstacle && rightSideChecking)
        {
            rightSideChecking = false;
            rightSideChecked = true;
        }

        //si el player esta arriba a la derecha nos movemos a la derecha
        if ((this.IsRight(player, 0f) && !rightSideChecked && !leftSideChecking) ||
            (this.IsLeft(player, 0f) && leftSideChecked && !leftSideChecking)
                    )
        {
            rightSideChecking = true;
            MoveToRight();
        }


        //si el player esta arriba a la izquierda nos movemos a la izquierda
        if ((this.IsLeft(player, 0f) && !leftSideChecked && !rightSideChecking) ||
            (this.IsRight(player, 0f) && rightSideChecked && !rightSideChecking))
        {
            leftSideChecking = true;
            MoveToLeft();
        }



        if (rightSideChecked && leftSideChecked)
        {
            rightSideChecked = false;
            rightSideChecking = false;
            leftSideChecked = false;
            leftSideChecking = false;
        }

        //no habia manera de subir
        return false;
    }
}
```

Estas son las 4 variasbles que se compartirían si lanzo las dos instancias de la función

```
bool leftSideChecking; 
bool rightSideChecking;
bool leftSideChecked;  
bool rightSideChecked;
```

Esta es el única línea de código que tendría que cambiar si pudiera lanzar las variables como hilos

```
        if (isItAWayToGetUp) //<--cambiaria esto
        {
            rigidBody.StopX();
            return true;
        }
 
        
        if (condicion)//<-- por esto
        {
            rigidBody.StopX();
            return true;
        }
```

y el método quedaría así:

```
private bool SearchWayToGetUp(bool condicion){...}
```

¿Alguna forma de poder hacer esto que digo?¿O alguna altenativa similar?
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas para que dos metodos utilicen la misma variable y no tengas problemas seria usar lock, es una palabra clave reservada de c# que bloquea una variable y deja esperando al método que la llama en segunda instancia, hasta que quede libre y puedas utilizarla. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ramiro!! Lo probaré a ver que tal va. Saludos.